# C storing address of a variable in array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

```
void main()
 {
 int a=10;
 int *j;
 *j=&a;
 b[]={1,2,3,4};
 b=j;
 }
```

Some one asked me is there any problem in this program ,i am just confused for me everything seems fine. Just curious to know.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon, and also [What should `main()` return in C and C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/what-should-main-return-in-c-and-c/18721336#18721336).  With a question like this, the immediate reaction is [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) with the obvious suggestion that you try compiling the code.  There's plenty there for the compiler to complain about.

Comment: You've not read the link referenced.  The code is only safe from castigation for the return type of `main()` if you're programming on Windows with a Microsoft compiler.

Comment: Sorry, thanks for your valuable comment ,i was just reading the link.Next time i will keep it in mind

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turn on all your compiler warnings and errors. Then it will tell you exactly what is wrong with the program.

`*j = &a;` is a constraint violation. `*j` has type `int` but `&a` has type `int *` which is incompatible.

You might have meant `j = &a;` which will point `j` to `a`.

`b[]={1,2,3,4};` is a syntax error. Maybe you meant `int b[]={1,2,3,4};` which would declare an array.

`b=j;` is a constraint violation because `b` is an array and arrays cannot be assigned to. (Technically: because `b` is an array, decays to an rvalue and rvalues cannot be assigned to).

However, `j = b;` would be OK and it would make `j` point to the first member of `b`;

`void main()` is non-portable, it should be `int main()` .

Comment: A big thanks to your clear explanation. I want to improve my skills on c, will you recommend me any book or website where i can learn and expertise c.

Comment: @Shreesh see [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) for book recommendations

Comment: Practice, practice, and more practice.  There are many decent books on C; there are also many poor ones.  The [ACCU](http://accu.org/) has many book reviews for C books.  King's [C Programming — A Modern Approach](http://www.amazon.com/Programming-Modern-Approach-2nd-Edition/dp/0393979504) is at least decent ([ACCU](http://accu.org/index.php?module=bookreviews&func=search&rid=1260)).